# date and time picker dialog box does not appears in android

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using html input fields in phonegap application for android.

But it doesn't appears the date and time picker on tapping these fields.

Thanks,
Narendra Singh

Comment: without posting what you have done how can somebody help you ?

Comment: I have added these jquery mobile js and css in the html file
index.html

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css"  />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<body>
<input type="date" id="txtdate" />
<input type="time" id="txttime" />
<input type="datetime" id="txtdatetime" />
</body>

I am using this and creating build using https://build.phonegap.com/apps
But it is not working in android.